# Using ssh remote plus grep

Tags: shell, ssh, arguments

I'm running a shell script like above:

```
vQtde=`ssh  user@server 'ls -lrt /mnta2/gvt/Interfaces/output/BI/sent/*.?${vDiaAnterior}* | grep "${vMDAtual}0[345678]:" |wc -l'`
```

And the return is on error: `ksh: /usr/bin/sh: arg list too long`

I know that the same script in local server return 9, how can I escape "" in remote grep ?

The variables are:

```
vDiaAtual=`date +%d`
vMesAtual=`date +%b`
vMDAtual=" $vMesAtual $vDiaAtual ";
vDiaAnterior=120614
```

Comment: @IgorChubin is right. +1 for posting your error message, but you have to read the error message! IT's telling you what is wrong. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is not with grep. The problem is following: the argument `/mnta2/gvt/Interfaces/output/BI/sent/*.?${vDiaAnterior}*` is expanded by shell (by `ksh` in the case) and the resulting list is too big.

It would be better to do simply `ls -lrt /mnta2/gvt/Interfaces/output/BI/sent/` and then add additional `grep` after it.

Something like:

```
ls -lrt /mnta2/gvt/Interfaces/output/BI/sent/ | grep "\..${vDiaAnterior}" | grep ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [information regarding that error message](http://www.unix.com/unix-advanced-expert-users/15577-arg-list-too-long.html), I'm not sure if escaping the quotes is the real issue here.

What is it that you're ultimately trying to do?  There's probably a slightly different way to approach it that avoids this problem.  It appears that you're trying to count the number of files with a certain "last modified" date.  Is this accurate?  If so, I highly recommend *against* using the output of `ls` to do that.  The output is inconsistent between platforms and can even change between versions.  The `find` utility is much better suited for this sort of thing.

Try something like this instead:

```
dir=/mnta2/gvt/Interfaces/output/BI/sent/
pattern="*.?${vDiaAnterior}*"
time= # Fill this in based on the "last modified" time that you're looking for

find $dir -iname "$pattern" -mtime $time -exec printf '.' \; | wc -c
```

You can omit using the extra variables, they're only there to make the code more readable on the webpage.

This will search the given directory for all files with names that match the specified wildcard pattern and with "last modified" times that match whatever you specify.  For each match found, the code `printf '.'` (which prints one dot to stdout) will be run.  `wc` then counts the number of dot characters, which will be equal to the number of matching files found.  The benefit of this method is that it minimizes the amount of data that needs to be piped between programs (including between the shell and `ls`).  `find` handles the wildcard matching internally instead of requiring the shell to expand the wildcard and pass the result to `ls`.  You're also only sending one character per matching file to `wc` instead of one long line of `ls` output per match.  That should reduce the chances that you encounter the "arg list too long" error.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem with this ways:
- Create a file .sh in local server receiving a parameters:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
```

vDiaAnterior="${1}";
vMDAtual="${2}";

ls -l /mnta2/gvt/Interfaces/output/BI/sent/*.?${vDiaAnterior}*AMA* | grep "${vMDAtual}[345678]:" | wc -l;

- Call remote :

> ssh user@server ". /mnta1/prod_med1/scriptsf/ver_jobs_3_horas.sh $vDiaAnterior '$vMDAtual'"
>   
>   Result: 9 Files.

Best Regards,
Cauca